# Changes in imaginary dielectric function to changes in Absorptivity of material

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, condensed-matter, reflection, absorption

I have a quick question that I am trying to get my head around. I am the looking at the increased absorption of light in some metal as temperature is increased. Lets say that the imaginary dielectric function $\epsilon$" increases by a factor of 3 at a given frequency, and $\epsilon$' does not change with temperature. This in turn means that
\begin{equation}
n^2-k^2 = \epsilon'
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
2nk = \epsilon''
\end{equation}
Where $n$ is the refractive index and $k$ is the extinction coefficient. Given these changes, can anything be accurately calculated regarding the corresponding change in $n$ and $k$? I would then like to feed these changes into the equation for the absorptivity, $A$ of the material (assuming no transmission).
\begin{equation}
A = 1- R
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
A = \frac{4n}{(n+1)^2 + k^2}
\end{equation}
Given the above changes in $\epsilon$' and $\epsilon$'', can the corresponding change in $A$ be found?

(Note: I would naively look at this and think, an increase in $\epsilon$'' must give a corresponding increase in $k$, indicating more absorption of light has occurred at the given frequency. But then this would indicate to me that at the absorptivity $A$ would drop, rather than increase as I would expect for a system absorbing more light. Am I missing something here?)

(edit: By working through the algebra from Fresnels and Maxwells equations, my initial assumption is incorrect. Changing $\epsilon''$ and keeping $\epsilon'$ fixed will change both $n$ and $k$. My current calculations seem to suggest that changes in $\epsilon''$ and in absorptivity, A, will match each other (approximately). Is this reasonable)

Answer (score 0):

### Specifics

In your thought experiment, you initially set $T \equiv 0$, you tripled $\epsilon''$, and you held $\epsilon'$ constant. You assumed that this translates directly to an increase only in $k$. When you set the three conditions this way, the result must mean that $n$ must decrease. Examine the first equation holding $\epsilon'$ constant and increasing $k$.

The resulting prediction on the behavior of $A = 4n / ((n + 1)^2 + k^2) $ is not straight forward.

In essence, with $T \equiv 0$, you have these three equations

$$A + R = 1$$
$$A = f(k)$$
$$R = g(n,k)$$

coupled with the two relationships between the set $(n,k)$ and $(\epsilon',\epsilon'')$. You almost appear to want to violate the algebraic limits on the number of independent parameters at your disposal for this system.

Later, you added a comment that the sample is to be semi-infinite. It was perhaps for this reason that you set $T \equiv 0$. In truth, you should instead set the sample width $d = \infty$. In this case, any light that enters the material never exists because $d = \infty$ *not because the material has to have an higher absorptivity for the light when the reflectivity decreases*.

### General

The starting equation is $1 = R + A + T$. Absorption is a distinct mode. "Light" (electromagnetic radiation) that is not reflected at the first boundary transmitted *into* the object. Light passing through the object that is not absorbed by the object and is not reflected at the second boundary is transmitted through the object.

The parameters $(n,k)$ or $(epsilon',epsilon'')$ that define $R$ and $A$ depend on the nature (chemistry and structure) of the material. In general, the two parameters in either set can be varied independently of each other.

Consider a sample with a finite thickness $d$. Suppose you make a statement that you want $T \equiv 0$. In doing so, you set a restriction on $(n,k)$ or $(\epsilon',\epsilon'')$. They are no longer independent of each other. When you hold $T \equiv 0$ and set $R = 1$, you are designing a material where all incoming light is reflected and nothing passes into the material to be absorbed. An example is to consider visible light reflecting on metals with plasmon free electron modes. Alternatively, when you hold $T \equiv 0$ and set $R = 0$, you are designing a material where no incoming light is reflected and all light passing into the material is absorbed *by the time the light reaches the second boundary at $d$*. An example is to consider microwaves passing through a polymer. In this latter case, you will find that the attenuation coefficient must be inversely proportional to the sample thickness.

For considerations working with a semi-infinite sample, the proper approach is not to assign $T \equiv 0$ *a priori*. Instead, the value $T \rightarrow 0$ because $d \rightarrow \infty$.

In summary, the two physical modes (reflection and absorption)  handled as independent phenomena. The minute you define $T \equiv 0$ in a sample with a finite thickness $d$, you define a condition on the relationship between the fundamental parameters $n$ and $k$ that must exist because $A + R = 1$ must hold true at the second boundary. Working with a semi-infinite sample decouples this restriction between the fundamental coefficients.

Comment: Specifically here I am focusing on absorptivity which is distinct from absorption and merely refers to the proportion of the incident light that is not reflected back at the light/metal interface. I am also assuming here that our sample is semi infinite so T = 0.

Comment: Just as an extra note: from working through the mathematics and plugging in some numbers of $\epsilon'$ and $\epsilon''$ suggest that changing $\epsilon''$ and keeping  $\epsilon'$ fixed results in both $n$ and $k$ changing (see edit).

Comment: Absorptivity arises from absorption. They are not distinct. The proportion of light not reflected is the proportion of light that is transmitted *into* the material. The proportion of light that is not absorbed by the material and not reflected at the outgoing interface is the proportion that is transmitted. A semi-infinite material will absorb all light that is not reflected, but not because the absorptivity is high rather because the thickness is infinite.

Comment: Ok, lets see if have understood this correctly. For this problem, you suggest that I would be better looking at something like $R$ + $T$ = 1 since anything not reflected by the boundary is transmitted and consequently absorbed by the sample. This reflectivity would then be reduced due to the increase in $\epsilon$'', meaning these plasmon modes have stronger damping associated with them. Is this more along the right lines?

Comment: I've added some thoughts on semi-infinite samples. For this case, you are best to start with $1 = R + A + T$ as the starting point. Set $(n,k)$ or $(\epsilon',\epsilon'')$ according to the physical system. Determine $R$. For a semi-infinite sample, $A = R - 1$ because $T \rightarrow 0$ as $d \rightarrow \infty$. You can calculate a relative rate of change $\Delta A/A$ per unit depth $d$.